# toggle between true and false in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to Elixir and am trying to toggle between `true` and `false` value like JS but i think that is not possible. is there an easy way to do that?

in the **component**

```
def update(assigns, socket) do
socket
|> assign(:show_password, false)
|> reply(:ok)
end


def handle_event("show_password", _params, socket) do
socket
|> assign(:show_password, !:show_password)
|> reply(:noreply)
end
```

in the **HTML**

```
 <i class="icon-closed_eye" phx-click="show_password" phx-target="<%= @myself %>"></i>
```

thank you all

Comment: Sure, it's possible, if you have the previous value. `:show_password` is an atom, not a value associated with that atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is, but, as mentioned in the comments, `:show_password` is an atom, not a boolean, so `!:show_password` doesn't make a lot of sense. However, you already have the value of `:show_password` in the socket's `:assigns`. So you can update it:

```rb
def handle_event("show_password", _params, socket) do
  socket
  |> assign(:show_password, !socket.assigns[:show_password])
  |> reply(:noreply)
end
```

Or even:

```rb
def handle_event("show_password", _params, socket) do
  socket
  |> update(:show_password, &(!&1))
  |> reply(:noreply)
end
```

And for the template, however, you still need to use something like a conditional:

```html
<%= if @show_password do %>
  <i class="icon-closed_eye" phx-click="show_password" phx-target="<%= @myself %>"></i>
<% else %>
  <i class="icon-opened_eye" phx-click="show_password" phx-target="<%= @myself %>"></i>
<% end %>
```

Assuming you also have an `icon-opened_eye` icon.

From there you can find other improvements. For instance you could avoid the conditional and use instead a helper function to define the class depending on the value of `@show_password`

Comment: Great explanation:)  thank you very much.